# Apache, Django and RestFramework: How to block requests on Apache from an unallowed host

Tags: django, apache

I've got an api running with apache, django and djangorestframework on let's say `api.example.com`.

This api is only accessed from `www.example.com`.

In django I get the following logs, which are correct:

```
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'x.x.x.x'. You may need to add 'x.x.x.x' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

How can I block requests from another host than `www.example.com` with Apache?

Answer (score 0):

Have you done:

```
if not DEBUG:
    # list of URL strings
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
        'www.example.com',
    ]
```

?

No other host should be catered.

Comment: I want to disable it with apache. I've got that setting already.